# Unresolved reference - Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, reference

I am trying to create a dictionaryin python, but facing an Unresolved reference 'count' error.

`dict = {"timestamp": 0.1, counter: 1}`

i have noticed that when Im creating a variable name counter with any numeric value the error disappears.

I am using Pycharm 2020.2.2.

Answer (score 2):

counter would need to be "counter"

dict = {"timestamp": 0.1, "counter": 1}

Comment: Thank you, can you ,maybe explain why counter ,use be string?

Comment: i don't know exactly what variable type you used for counter but dictionary keys have be to immutable So doing something like this counter = 'mykey' or counter = 1 and then running dict = {"timestamp": 0.1, counter: 1} would both work.  .